# How to import willReturn(), hasSize() and is() methods for a Spring Test?

Tags: spring, junit, spring-security, mockito

I'm following a Baeldung article to make a test for a Controller in my Spring application. It's called "Testing in Spring Boot" from June 7th, 2021. The code that I'm following only is in the 8th section of it.

I'm having trouble importing the three methods mentioned in the title. I don't know where to import them from.

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = UserController.class)
public class UserControllerUnitTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mvc;

@MockBean
private UserServiceImpl userService;

@Test
public void givenUser_whenGetUsers_thenReturnJsonArray() throws Exception {
    User user = new User("ime", "prezime", "imeprezime@email.com", "1234");

    List<User> allUsers = List.of(user);

    given(userService.getUsers().willReturn(allUsers));

    mvc.perform(get("/users")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name", is(user.getFirstName())));
}
}
```

How do I add those? Another small question that doesn't have to be answered... is this a good enough unit test for the @Controller class?

Answer (score 0):

`willReturn()` should be statically imported from Mockito framework:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*
```

`hasSize()` and `is()` are the static methods and can be imported using:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
```

Comment: I was able to add the hasSize() and is() but had no luck with willReturn(). It's still giving me an error which says when I hover over it: "Cannot resolve method 'willReturn' in 'List'".

Comment: This is because you are trying to call the `willReturn` method from the `getUsers()` return object. You should close the parenthesis first, like so: `    given(userService.getUsers()).willReturn(allUsers);`